# Solution verification: Given that $x=\cos \theta$ I want to find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in terms of $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, implicit-differentiation

Given that $x=\cos \theta$ I want to find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in terms of $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$.

My work $\frac{dx}{dy}=-\sin {\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dy}$, rearanging gives $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{1}{-\sin{\theta}}$. Differentiating again with respect to x gives

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{-\sin\theta}+\frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}=\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{1}{-\sin\theta})\frac{1}{-\sin\theta}+-\frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^3\theta}=\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}\frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}-\frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^3\theta}$. However, when I checked the answer on the student room it did not contain  $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ in the $\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}\frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}$ bit. The way I get it is just by directly substitution what I have for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in the previous part. Could someone explain to me why this is wrong?

Comment: In your equation for $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$, you should also multiply with $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$ to the second term.

Comment: @Tavish thanks for spotting that, I forgot to carry that through onto LaTeX (originally I did the problem on a piece of paper). Any idea how the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ could disappear or why it shouldn't be there in the first place?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Chain Rule.

Comment: hi @K.defaoite, I think I have used it correctly haven't I? I differentiated $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ with respect to x to get $\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}\frac{dy}{dx}$ . Is this wrong?

Comment: Hello, in the problem I am looking at we are given that $x=\cos\theta$ and that $y(x)=(-1)^ny(-x)$. Regarding the transformation, I just took the reciprocal of both sides as to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equal to something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\frac{dy}{d\theta}=t$. Then, $$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dt}{d\theta} \cdot \frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{d^2 y}{d\theta^2}\cdot \frac{d\theta}{dx} $$

There shouldn’t be a $\frac{dy}{dx}$ here.

Comment: You are right, thank you for taking the time to show me this approach. I have question: How do you intuitively think about it without making the substitution? Is it just remembering that when differentiating a derivative with respect to a variable that is not in it one performs the operation that you have mentioned?

Comment: @MathsWizzard You should see $y$ as a function of $\theta$, because of the presence of the term $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$. Likewise, $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ is also a function of $\theta$, and now it will be obvious that we should multiply with $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$ instead of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: thank you very much for this clarification now. My knowledge gap has been filled.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dy}\right)^{-1}\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[-\csc(\theta)\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right]=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left[-\csc(\theta)\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right]\frac{d\theta}{dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake happened at the start, when $\sin \theta$ turned into $\sin y$. It should be $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{dy}{d\theta}\csc \theta$$. Then $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-\frac{d}{d \theta}(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\csc \theta)}{\frac{dx}{d \theta}}.$$ You can take it from here.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that. It doesn't change my algebra though as I proceeded with $\sin \theta$ my mistake was in differentiating $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {dy}{d\theta}\frac {d\theta}{dx}\\
\frac {d}{dx} \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {d}{dx}(\frac {dy}{d\theta}) \frac {d\theta}{dx} + \frac {dy}{d\theta}\frac {d}{dx}\frac {d\theta}{dx}\\
\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = (\frac {d^2y}{d\theta^2}\frac {d\theta}{dx}) \frac {d\theta}{dx} + \frac {dy}{d\theta}(\frac {d^2\theta}{dx^2})\\
\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac {d^2y}{d\theta^2}(\frac {d\theta}{dx})^2 + \frac {dy}{d\theta}\frac {d^2\theta}{dx^2}\\
$

$\frac {d\theta}{dx} = -\frac {1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
\frac {d^2\theta}{dx^2} = -\frac {x}{(1-x^2)^\frac 32}$

$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac {d^2y}{d\theta^2}\left(\frac {1}{1-x^2}\right) - \frac {dy}{d\theta}\left(\frac {x}{(1-x^2)^{\frac 32}}\right)$

Or

$\frac {dx}{d\theta} = -\sin\theta\\
\frac {d\theta}{dx} = -\csc\theta\\
\frac {d}{dx}\frac {d\theta}{dx} = \frac {d}{d\theta}(-\csc\theta\frac) {d\theta}{dx}\\
\frac {d}{dx}\frac {d\theta}{dx} = -\csc^2\theta\cot\theta\\
\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac {d^2y}{d\theta^2}\csc^2\theta - \frac {dy}{d\theta}\csc^2\theta\cot\theta$